# How to pass Parcelable object from child to parent activity?

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm building a small app that requiere authentication. In my main activity I have a `Parcelable` class named "user" that contains the username and password of an user, when a user click on a button it starts a new activity passing that user class. It works like a charm, in the child activity the user fill the form to authenticate, then when user press the back button, I would like to send the "user" class back to my main activity.

Is it possible to do that ??

Comment: http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3/. check this might help

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i already know how to send data from parent to child activity.What i would like to know is, how to return the data from child to parent activity when pressing the back button ?

Comment: use `startActivityForResult` and override `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start your child activity with:

```
startActivityForResult(startIntent, 1);
```

In your child activity, intercept the back button and append your data:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("key", yourDataHere);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And get data inside parent activity inside `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        DataType yourData = (DataType) data.getParcelableExtra("key");
        //Do whatever you want with yourData
    }
}
```